# Unable to connect a remote disk using afp

Tags: macos, afp

I have two network drives in my local network - one is WDMyCloud device and the other is a USB hard drive connected to AirPort Extreme. All of a sudden the mac cannot connect these devices using AFP. I am able to connect the disk using SMB.

SO if I use smb://wdmycloud-device it works fine but when trying afp://wdmycloud-device I'm getting the following error:

> There was a problem connecting to the server “wdmycloud-device”.
>   Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator

I'm using OS X 10.11.5.

Comment: this is what I found in the log: 10/07/2016 07:42:17.062 com.apple.kextd[50]: /System/Library/Filesystems/AppleShare/afpfs.kext - dependency 'com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword' not found.
10/07/2016 07:42:17.062 com.apple.kextd[50]: Can't load /System/Library/Filesystems/AppleShare/afpfs.kext - failed to resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you should know that AFP is deprecated as of 10.11 and SMB should always be used where possible.
The next OS X (10.12) will drop AFP support entirely.

Besides that, Given that the log is suggesting the kernel extension for AFPFS is unable to load due to missing dependencies you may want to look at either reinstalling the 10.11.5 Combo Update or reinstalling the whole OS over the top.

Combo Update can be grabbed here:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1876?viewlocale=en_AU&locale=en_AU

For the reinstall, make sure you have a known good backup with time machine or similar.
https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201250

Re-Install El Capitan by going to the App Store, search for it, download it and install once completed. It will install 10.11.5.

Comment: Reinstalling the combo update did the trick for me.